# Where is the Text Mode Preview of Device in the Android Studio 2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I just upgraded to Android studio 2.1. I'm editing a layout in text mode. Before the upgrade, I could see all of the changes that occurred as I added widgets to the layout because there was a preview of the device on the right hand side. Now, I can't find the thing. Does anyone know how to add it?
Here is a screen shot...[image]

Comment: I still have a "Preview" tool, docked on the right. I run Linux, not OS X, so I don't know if the IDEA/Android Studio tools behave differently between the operating systems. Look in View > Tool Windows and see if you see "Preview".

Comment: Word. That's it. You can answer it and I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, your Preview tool [was eaten by a grue](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/you-are-likely-to-be-eaten-by-a-grue).

Normally, there should be a docked "Preview" tool when you are in text-editing mode on a layout resource. If that's missing, check in View > Tool Windows and see if "Preview" is there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to following option from menu bar.

View->Tool Windows->Preview